# Can we use chi-square distribution and central limit theorem to find the approximate normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, chi-squared

If $X_1,\ldots,X_i,\ldots,X_n$ are same normal distribution, $X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,σ^2)$,
and they are independent.
$$
Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2} n.
$$

What is the distribution of the square of the normal distribution?like $X_i^2$,and,what is it mean and variance?

I am trying to turn this Z into a normal distribution

can we use chi-square distribution and central limit theorem to find the approximate normal distribution ?

How to do it？

I do not quite understand the chi-square distribution and central limit theorem,
could you answer this question in detail?

Any help would be much appreciated!

### re-edit：

I do this works:
$$
Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2} n= σ^2\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i}{σ}\right)^2.
$$ 
this is a chi-square distribution,and mean $= nσ^2$, var${}=2nσ^2$.

is this right?

and how to use CLT to find the approximate normal distribution?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried? Also are those $X_i$ independent?

Comment: thanks,and sorry,I wrote it wrongly,Z should be$Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^2} n$.,I have re-edited the question.

Comment: "$Z\sim N\left(σ^2,\frac{2σ^2} n \right)\text{ ?}$(Someone gave me this answer, but did not explain)" Well, then "someone" was very wrong.

Comment: @Did,Can you help me explain the correct answer?any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This post would be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260391/central-limit-theorem-confusion

Comment: This post would be helpful:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260391/central-limit-theorem-confusion

Comment: "The correct answer" is that $$\sqrt{n}(Z_n-\sigma^2)$$ converges in distribution to a centered normal distribution. The reason is the standardest CLT. Do you know the statement of the CLT?

Comment: but $Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2} n$,$X_i^2$ not $X_i$,Is this also converges in distribution to a centered normal distribution?@DidThank you very much for your patience.

Comment: Do you think this is an objection at all? Then you need to think harder about the problem...

Answer (score 1):

There is no positive normal random variable!

Comment: you are righ,,but,can we use chi-square distribution and central limit theorem to find the approximate normal distribution ?

Comment: @ysbbs This is **another** question. Please ask from the start the question you intend to ask.

Comment: I have re-edited the question again...thank you for you any help.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution can not reach negative value but can still be approximated by normal approximation, so I don't think Murthy's answer is persuasive enough.
  And actually, $$(\frac{X_{i}}{\sigma })^{2}\sim \chi ^{2}(1), with\:finite\:  mean\: 1\: and\: finite\:variance\: 2; since\:Xi\sim i.i.d,\\ (\frac{X_{i}}{\sigma })^{2}\sim i.i.d,\\by\:Central\:Limit\:Theorem,\\ \sqrt{n}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}((\frac{X_{i}}{\sigma })^{2}-1)}{n})=\sqrt{n}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{X_{i}}{\sigma })^{2}}{n}-1) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,2)\:as\: n \rightarrow +\infty \\$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X_i/\sigma\overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,1)$, then $W_i = (X_i/\sigma)^2\overset{iid}{\sim}\chi^2_1$  and $\mathbb{E}(W_i) = 1$, $\mathbb{Var}(W_i) = 2$. Therefore, if $\bar{W}_n$ is the sample mean, we have by the classic CLT
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{W}_n-1)\overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,2).
$$
Based on the above we obtain that for large $n$,
$$
\bar{W}_n \overset{approx}{\sim}N(1,\dfrac{2}{n}).
$$